# multiple ajax request in yii

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

my ajax links not working after rendering inside another view via ajax. i used delegate function with ajax to prevent it. In first view its working well but in second page it sends multiple request for some click.

Here is my code:

```
$i=0;
foreach($contents as $conts){

   echo CHtml::ajaxLink(conts->name, 
       array('frontend/dataView','id'=> $conts->content_id,'cat_id'=>$cat->parent_id ), 
       array('update'=>'#level3rd','beforeSend'=>'function(){$(\'body\').undelegate(\'#cont'.$i.'\', \'click\');}',),
       array('id'=>'cont'.$i,'onclick'=>"makeContactive(this.id);"));
$i++;
}
```

Comment: This code is in your view, right?

How are you rendering it in your controller? You is using render or renderPartial?

Comment: yes this comes in my view. i render it using renderPartial in controller.

Answer (score 0):

You probably are rendering your view in this way:

```
$this->renderPartial($view, $params);
```

Try this:

```
$this->renderPartial($view, $params, false, true);
```

Comment: no i used the same $this->renderPartial($view, $params, false, true);

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is the case, but... some things are tied with jquery after the page is loaded.

For example I use chosen. I have a function that ties the chosen dropdown to all the dropdowns that have a specific class. Now if I bring the code with Ajax those dropdowns do not use chosen because the function that tied them all ran 1 time in the beginning. If I want to make the dropdowns work with chosen again then I need to rerun the function that ties chosen to selects again after I make the ajax call.

Are you sure this is not also the case with your ajax links?

Answer (score 0):

onclick events dont work on dynamically loaded content.

in the old jQuery you hand to bind your clicks with .live('click') (before 1.7)
Now since jQuery 1.7 you can use the .on('click').

Although you should me sure you dont make the same mistake as i did.

`$('#myAnchor').on('click', myclickFunction)`

this works fine on pageload, but not on dynamic content.
the right way to do it is.

`$('#parentElement').on('click', '#myAnchor', 'customEvenName', myclickFunction)`

the parent element here should be one that is not dynamically loaded

**The actual benefit of all this is, that you can put you .on('click') events anywhere, usually somewhere in a js script you include, so that all events are only loaded once.**